# Bathroom fan not working after adding socket

Tags: electrical, bathroom, fans

DIY electrics on the go here.

I've been tinkering in my loft adding a fused spur socket off my upper lighting ring for CCTV cameras (I know this is frowned upon but I have carried out the work to the best of my ability and labeled the double socket as such being on a 6A breaker. (Cameras pull maximum of 0.6A between them)

Since doing this my bathroom fan doesn't work...

The cable I spliced into for the socket is another 3 core and earth unrelated to the area of wiring in question posing a problem. I will mention here I have undone all my work in an attempt to see if the fan would power on and alas it doesn't so what I've added doesn't seem to be the problem.

I have a double switch with one pole powering the light fitting in the ceiling, and the other pole powering a separate inline fan that sits in the loft.

The light fitting switches on regardless of which side I put the cables (either switch) but neither switch will power the inline fan.

I check the fan and it works, checked for continuity of both live and neutral to the fan from the switch (just in case I'd accidentally caught a cable as I was clambering around my loft) and both check out. I then proceeded to run a cable from said fan directly to switch through the loft entry and the fan still wouldn't work.

So I swapped the switch and still no luck, even tried another fan I had lying around and no luck.

I have seemingly a good fan, cable and switch but yet the fan which did work before now doesn't.

Does anybody have any ideas before I call a sparkie?

LATEST EDIT WE FIXED IT!!

Thanks for your quick replies everyone!

Okay so of course it's a voltage issue, followed the perm live back from the switch to a mess of chocolate block connectors and I had a neutral wire snapped off in the block so I assume kicked a cable as I was clambering. Checking for voltage at the switch gave me the new perspective I needed to resolve my issue. Thanks for pointing out I'd checked continuity but not load.

Comment: Could you post diagrams and photos (before and after if available) of your current wiring connections and what you are trying to achieve? Have you checked your main panel for a tripped breaker? What do you mean by a "fused spur socket"? What part of the world are you in and what kind of AC setup do you have?

Comment: You checked for continuity, but did you check voltage?  Stuff like this is sometimes caused by a broken wire inside wire insulation/cable.  It will check perfect one second and just touch it, it will not work the next second.  Electricity usually not that hard.  A good fan, a good switch and power connected it should work.

Comment: was the fan on a switch loop maybe